# Could I reject an accepted PhD admit after April 15?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I have already clicked on the acceptance of an admit(without funding). The deadline for response is Apr.15th, and I did not have any other options at that time. However, I just received a funding offer from a top University. I am wondering if I could reject the accepted admit. If yes, how to reject it very very politely? Will this affect credibility?

Comment: Two days after the 15th to accept a better alternative offer with funding? I think it's OK - they have time to make another offer. But be very polite as the answer to the duplicate says.

Comment: I voted to reopen because this situation seems a bit different than the other question.  Namely: the first offer was without funding and the US April 15th deadline issue is present.

Comment: Agree @Kimball that the funding issue is an important distinction. Also the poster of the question marked duplicate seems to have had a bit more interaction with the program whose offer they asked about declining, including a statement to the effect that the accepted offer was poster's first choice.

Comment: Note that the Community vote indicates the OP agreed that the linked Q answered the question.